# How to create a WIX installation for ASP.NET WebSites?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, installation, wix, vs-web-site-project

I am aware of this tutorials
http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/putting-it-to-use
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/WixTutorial.aspx

... but I can't find a quick solution for installing web sites and configuring IIS. 
Is it necessary to manually add each file of the site?

Comment: Read wix.chm file from (http://wix.sourceforge.net/) that will help you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add each file manually.  Instead, you can use [Paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/08/31/zen-of-paraffin.aspx) to harvest the files needed from your web project.

I configured it so that it is automatically run during a build (local or on the server) by manually modifying the Wix project file to add a BeforeBuild action.  Here is an example, you can use this as a starting point.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Set the WebClient.wxs file as not read-only -->
    <Exec Command="attrib -R &quot;$(ProjectDir)WebClient.wxs&quot;" />
    <!-- Run paraffin to generate the wix component for the web client. This assumes that web project has already been packaged. 
    This is automatically done on the build server by setting the property 'DeployOnBuild' to true. -->
    <Exec Command="paraffin -update WebClient.wxs -dir ..\RM.Web\obj\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\" />
    <!-- Set the WebClient.wxs file back as read-only -->
    <Exec Command="attrib +R &quot;$(ProjectDir)WebClient.wxs&quot;" />
  </Target>
```